# Time difference condition in rails using database Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I want such condition that after for example 5 days of data creation user cannot edit that data again.
  Since i am using Mongodb as database

```
include Mongoid::Timestamps
```

which save database in

```
 "created_at" : ISODate("2013-03-28T05:19:55.418Z")       in this format.
```

I want  any idea to make condition that can check 5 days to this created_at date format.

Comment: will this helpful `@user.created_at + 5.days`

Comment: How to bring today's  date(now) in Mongoid formate and bring difference to created date? if this is <= 5 then edit method will work otherwise not.

Comment: Can you try this? `(@user.created_at + 5.days).strftime("%F") <= Time.now.strftime("%F")`. This will convert both into dates and check them

Answer (score 1):

you can check out only documents from 4 day ago or earlier:

> db.datecol.find({ "date" : { $gte : (new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (4*
>   24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) } } ).sort( { "date": 1 } )

The query will get all documents on datecol collection which "date" filed is earlier than o equals to 4 days ago.

Regards,
Moacy

Comment: So you can use the mentioned condition:

{ "date" : { $gte : (new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (4* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) } }

to limit the documents your system users can edit.

Regards,

Moacy

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this via a validation

```
class UserInfo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  validate :save_within_5_days_of_creation

  def save_within_5_days_of_creation
    self.created_at + 5.days < Time.now 
  end
end
```

I'm not sure about whether you can check the Mongoid::Timestamps directly against Time.now, but I think you should be able to